# Unknown server tag 'rsweb:ReportViewer'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am a newbie to asp.net and trying to use report viewer control for my reports in sharepoint.

In my web.config file i added this line:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer" TypeName="*" Safe="True"/>
```

In my aspx page I registered the assembly

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
```

It gives me this error:

**The control type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' is not allowed on this page. The type is not registered as safe.**

When I change the code in my aspx page to this

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
```

I get this:

**An error occurred during the processing of . Unknown server tag 'rsweb:ReportViewer'.**

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Are you using the correct version of the ReportViewer? I know there's a 9.0 and a 10.0. That's tripped me up when I first started using it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the ReportViewer, that can be found on microsoft downloads.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a941c6b2-64dd-4d03-9ca7-4017a0d164fd

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. Saved me tons of time and frustration.